# Is @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() required with Sitecore 8 MVC?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

Is the following call to `VistorIndentification()` still required within Sitecore 8 MVC layouts / views?

```csharp
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

Even without it, page visits appeared to be tracked in Tracker.Current.Contact.System.VisitCount and within the Experience Profile information.

What feature or tracking ability is dependant on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234328/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-visitoridentification-control

Comment: I assume this is still valid; the VI helps Sitecore with robot detection. I've not checked for updated documentation however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think your site will break without it, but I would highly recommend adding it in for full xDB support. Without it, I believe all your traffic may be treated as a 'robot' and will not get tracked. A few articles referencing using the visitor identification:

http://www.daveleigh.co.uk/sitecore-7-5-mvc-enabling-analytics-xdb/
http://www.daveleigh.co.uk/sitecore-xdb-and-setting-up-mongo-replica-sets/

Comment: Interestingly it was that first link that made me raise the question, as it suggests that tracking might not occur without VisitorIdentification() being present whereas I was seeing tracking info without it.

Comment: Ran across a KB article that says it should be included in the head of the layout for xDB to work correctly: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445

Specifically: "Ensure that all of your layout pages contain the <sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" /> tag (@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() helper for MVC websites) in the <head> section."

Comment: Fun fact- this ultimately calls a JS file.  If your mouse moves- you're not a robot.  You would only see tracking info without it if you set `Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots` to **false**.