# Sitecore 8.1 MongoDB collection not updated

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-xdb

I have installed MongoDB (3.0.15) in my local Sitecore 8.1 (initial Release) instance and have enabled the following setting/config

Enabled "Xdb.Enabledand" and "Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" in Sitecore.xdb.config

Enabled "enableTracking" for all my sites in mysitedefinition.config

Enabled Sitecore.MvcAnalytics.config file

Disabled all the xDBCloud related files

Added mongodb connection strings in connectionstrings.config

Also started mongod service from commend prompt and made my session timeout is 1 minute instead of 20 minute in web.config

after all I have made few visits to my site pages i.e home page,about us,products,new pages but  interaction data does not appear in the collection database for the visited pages (analytics and tracking.live databases created)
(All my pages have the identification tag & have license for mongodb)

Please suggest how to solve this issue/how verify my collection db working?
Also I have configured processing/reporting servers in my local instance but contact and history collection databases not appeared in xDB- please suggest

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Do you have 'VisitorIdentification' in your layout? Or adblock in your browser?MVC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120608/is-html-sitecore-visitoridentification-required-with-sitecore-8-mvc WEB FORMS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234328/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-visitoridentification-control

Comment: Yes Marek. All my page layouts have the visitor identification tag