# Sitecore 8 Experience Analytics Reports are Empty

Tags: report, sitecore, analytics, sitecore8

I'm very new to Sitecore. I'm running Sitecore 8 (rev. 150621) in local machine. When I check in Experience Profile dashboard there are Profiles created named "Anonymous" and I have created contacts using xDB [Contact Creator](https://github.com/ianjohngraham/CoreBlimey.Utils/tree/master/CoreBlimey.Utils/xDB%20Contact%20Creator) (Market Place Module). I have some records(visits etc.) under these contacts also.Problem is when I check in Experience Analytics dashboard visits are empty.

I tried [Refreshing Executive Dashboard/ Experience Analytics reports](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/xDB/reports/how-to-refresh-reports/), didn't get any result for the Experience Analytics reports.

In my current site I have couple of pages (Items).I have also tried with some personas but no luck.

How ever I can see data is populated in the Analytic Database (Mongo and SQL)

**LOG:**

```
    6984 10:09:56 INFO  MemoryMonitor initialized. Threshold: 2 GB. Interval: 00:00:05
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'maintenanceService'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  Cache created: 'taxonomy.campaigngroups' (max size: 20MB, running total: 848MB)
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  Cache created: 'taxonomy.channels' (max size: 20MB, running total: 868MB)
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  Cache created: 'taxonomy.assets' (max size: 20MB, running total: 888MB)
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/aggregator'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/contactProcessing'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/cleanup'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/recovery'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/rebuildAgent'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/historyWorker'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/historyCompletionCheck'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/automationAggregator'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/automationRangeManager'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'aggregation/automationCleanupService'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Automation aggregation SubsystemLoader hook initialized.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'processing/taskAgent'.
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  Cache created: 'rules' (max size: 800KB, running total: 889MB)
    6984 10:09:57 INFO  Cache created: '[FieldReaderCache]' (max size: 5MB, running total: 894MB)
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'pathAnalyzer/newMapAgent'.
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'pathAnalyzer/dailyMapAgent'.
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'pathAnalyzer/smartMergeAgent'.
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  [Path Analyzer]() Path Analyzer subsystem hook initialized.
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  [Analytics]: Started background service for 'experienceAnalytics/reduce/agent'.
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: ExperienceAnalytics reduce subsystem initialized.
    6984 10:09:59 INFO  Scheduler - Initializing

6984 10:10:11 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: ExperienceAnalytics SegmentInitializer
6984 10:10:11 INFO  Cache created: 'ReportDataCache' (max size: 50MB, running total: 2077MB)
ManagedPoolThread #5 10:10:12 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
4828 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/contactProcessing'.
7736 10:10:12 INFO  Cache created: 'Task Manager - tasks' (max size: 100 bytes, running total: 2077MB)
9016 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/historyCompletionCheck'.
7660 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/automationCleanupService'.
4536 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/historyWorker'.
7756 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'processing/taskAgent'.
8348 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/automationAggregator'.
6948 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/aggregator'.
7388 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Registered aggregation context for the pool 'live'.
7388 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Registered aggregation context for the pool 'live'.
7388 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/recovery'.
7936 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/automationAggregator'.
7736 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/rebuildAgent'.
 732 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Registered aggregation context for the pool 'live'.
 732 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Registered aggregation context for the pool 'live'.
 732 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/cleanup'.
4692 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/automationRangeManager'.
7660 10:10:12 INFO  Cache created: 'ReportingStorageProviderProperties.Properties' (max size: 100 bytes, running total: 2077MB)
8452 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: Created new agent instance: 'aggregation/automationAggregator'.
9016 10:10:12 DEBUG [Analytics]: MongoDbHistoryTaskManager - deactivated history task.
6984 10:10:12 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: WebApiInitializer
6984 10:10:12 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: Filter (Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.Filters.CacheHeaderFilterAttribute) added
6984 10:10:12 INFO  Sitecore.Social: The Social remote events are initialized.
```

Comment: Do the logs indicate if the aggregation agents are running?

Comment: Hope I have copied the correct potion from log. Its looks like the Aggregation process is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sergey Plashenko (Sitecore Community) now Experience Analytics Reports shows data.
In my case I had data in `TrafficOverview` but no data in `ReportDataView` in SQL Analytics Db and also had data in `Contacts` and `Interactions` in Mongo.

This is the link for Forum Post [Sitecore 8 Experience Analytics Reports are Empty](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/9/p/1028/3528#3528)

**Solution:**

Open the reporting database using the SQL Management Studio and run the following query:

> SELECT * FROM [Segments]

If the table is empty please perform the following:

1. Open the *sitecore/admin/redeploymarketingdata.aspx* page and click
   the Redeploy Segments button.
2. Open the reporting database using SQL
   Management studio and run the following query:

> UPDATE [dbo].[Segments] SET  [DeployDate] = '2001-08-05
>       08:44:45.500'

3. Rebuild the reporting database.

Answer (score 4):

One other thing to check: Make sure you have the `VisitorIdentification` tag in your site. Without it visits won't be recorded.

Also, you can check you are getting the correct data for visits in MongoDB by looking at the `Interactions` collection.

To check in SQL, run a view called `ReportDataView` in the Analytics database -this will tell you if you have data going into your reports.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Surprisingly there are no data rows in `ReportDataView` but have data in `Interactions` in mongo

Comment: Ok, try going to control panel in the Sitecore shell and then click deploy marketing definitions and then generate some hits- worth a shot

Comment: anything in the reportdataview now?

Comment: To add some clarification to @golden grahams answer, visits are recorded regardless if the VisitorIdentification tag is present or not. It is required so it determine if the visitor is a human or robot. If its identified as a robot, it won't be given a session nor track its visit. Improving performance and accuracy of Analytical data .

Comment: I did as you ( @golden grahams ) suggested. I can see that last hits are recorded in Experience Profile under name `anonymous` and `unknown`. Guess I should wait to aggregation process to run or rebuild the xDB. Any how I can see data in `TrafficOverview`. what can be the season that data shows in Experience Profile and not in Experience Analytic ?

Comment: @jRobbins as ur clarification what if my visits/hits are identified as robot. How can I verify that and fix it. I recently noted that when I try to search on Stackoverflow it redirects me to `Human Verification page`.

Comment: Experience Profile accesses MongoDB directly, whereas Experience analytics accesses the aggregated analytics data rolled up into Fact tables in SQL.

Comment: Your visits won't be identified as a robot using the VisitorIdentification tag so add it to your Sitecore Layouts so it appears on every page of your site - more info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7234789/902125. I wouldn't worry how Stackoverflow treats your searches relating to how Sitecore identifies human

Comment: @golden grahams thank you for the clarification. Is there any way to configure Experience Analytic to directly access mongo as it show the previous day/past data.

Comment: no, there isnt a way to do this. It's all designed to look at the SQL data. It might be worth rebuilding your reporting database again to see if you have any data coming through now.

Comment: At the moment I have couple of solutions ( Sitecore Instance) non of them shows Experience Analytic data, no rows in `ReportDataView`. I really need to figure this out.

Comment: have you rebuilt the reporting database yet? http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/01/10/rebuilding-sitecore-8-analytics-indexes/

Comment: Also check the version of MongoDb that you're running to make sure it is compatible.

Comment: Even rebuild didn't work. I'm using Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150621 and have Mongo 3.0. I have data in `TrafficOverview` but no data in `ReportDataView` and olso have data in `Contacts` and `Interactions` in mongo